# Hiding parameters (sensitive information) from URL of an MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on Asp.Net MVC 5. When i click a link (placed in another website) I  navigate to UserDetails.cshtml page. **Basically that 3rd party site is passing the UserName & Password to my site & using that I authorize & display further user info.**

It's fine but the Url is looking like this

localhost:8080//Admin/UserDetails/UserName/PWD.

I don't want to show the UserName & Password in URL i.e URL should look something like :

localhost:8080//Admin/UserDetails/

One possible solution could be rewrite the URL in IIS ([http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx](http://Refer%20this%20link))

But I believe there is an easier way to handle this by using the routing mechanism of MVC.

Please help me to figure out the same.

**EDIT :** 
As many of you are confused **why I am not doing a Form Post here**, let me re-frame my question.  I have no control over the third party application, so I cant request them to do a form Post to my MVC application. Again the 3rd party application is a Oracle Reporting application (OBI), so doing a POST from that application might not be feasible too...

Comment: Why not post the data?!

Comment: Let me re-frame my question.  I have no control over the third party application, so I cant request them to do a form Post to my MVC application. Again the 3rd party application is a Oracle Reporting application (OBI), so doing a POST from that application might not be feasible too...

Answer (score 2):

Let me reverse engineer your requirements from your question:

> I want to have an URI that when invoked will give access to a secured section of my website. This URI must be clicked by visitors of a third-party site, whom I give that URI to. I want to hide the credentials from the URI.

You cannot do this, the requirements are conflicting. You cannot hand out URIs that will authenticate anyone who fires a request to that URI.

You could do something with a token (like `http://your-site/auth/$token`), but then still, anyone with access to that URI can use it to authenticate themselves, or simply put it up on their own website.

If you have data you want to expose to a third-party site, let that site perform an HTTP request (with tokens, usernames, headers or whatever you want to use to authenticate) in the background to your site, and display the response in their site. Then the visitor won't see that traffic, can't share the URI and all will be secure.

Comment: Token auth is a good way to handle such scenario & I have thought of this approach too, but the said third party application is not having capability to generate TOKEN too.

Comment: As you mentioned even in my case the third party application is authenticating the user before passing the control to my ASP.Net MVC  application but post that what ever URL gets can be saved / Bookmark by the user & if anyone else also uses that url, he/she impersonate the same privilege  :(

Answer (score 1):

No. No. NO. Like seriously, NO. Any sensitive information should be sent via a post body over a secure connection (HTTPS). You can't "hide" information in a GET request, because it's all part of the URI, or the location of a particular resource. If you remove a portion, it's an entirely different location.

**UPDATE**

I find it extremely hard to believe that any third-party application that needs to authenticate via HTTP and isn't designed by a chimp with a typewriter, wouldn't support a *secure* method to do so, especially if it's an Oracle application. I'm not familiar with this particular app, but, and no offense meant here, but I would more easily believe that you've missed something in the documentation or simply haven't found the right way to do it *yet* before I'd believe you *have* to send clear-text credentials over GET.

Regardless, as I said previously, there's no way to hide information in a GET request. All data in a GET is part of the URL, and therefore is plainly visible in the browser location bar or whatever. Unfortunately, I have no advice for you other than to look closer at the documentation, even reach out to Oracle if you have to. Whether by post or something like OAuth, there almost has to be another way.

Comment: Updated my question mentioning why I cant use Form POST in this scenario.